# Draw "EditorGUILayout.FloatField" with a custom label after the field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a custom editor window and I want to draw `EditorGUILayout.FloatField` on it. if I write this:

```
EditorGUILayout.FloatField("change val", someFloatValue);
```

a label appears in front of the field. But I want it to appears behind the field. Also, I'd like to change simple text with a texture.

What I have now:

[image: EditorGUILayout.FloatField with a default label position.jpg]

What I'd like to achieve:

[image: EditorGUILayout.FloatField with a label behind.jpg]

---

**UPD.** I missed important information:
 A mouse behavior over a texture must be the same as over a FloatField label, i.e. if I click on the texture and start dragging a cursor - the float value in the field must changes

---

I couldn't find an option to do it in a simple way. Maybe I miss something.

Is it possible not to create a lot of auxiliary classes for that simple action? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've made an **UGLY** workaround for the field (also for `IntField`). 
If remove all redundant code that I used for content filling - it will be pretty short...

A simplified example looks like this:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainWindow : EditorWindow {

    private float floatFieldVal;    
    private Rect groupFloatFieldRect;


    [MenuItem("Examples/Test")]
    static void Init() {
        MainWindow window = (MainWindow)GetWindow(typeof(MainWindow), false, "My Empty Window");
        window.Show();
    }


    void OnGUI() {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(); {

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(); { 
                GUILayout.Button("Button 1");
                GUILayout.Button("Button 2");
                GUILayout.Button("Button 3");
            } EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

            EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUILayout.Width(300)); { 
                // never load asset in the loop :)
                string assetFullPath = "Assets/Editor/Test.guiskin";
                var fakeFieldGUISkin = (GUISkin)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(assetFullPath, typeof(GUISkin));
                GUIStyle fakeFieldStyle = fakeFieldGUISkin.GetStyle("test");

                // place fake floatField right over a real field texture button
                Rect test = new Rect(groupFloatFieldRect);
                test.position = new Vector2(test.x + groupFloatFieldRect.width - 20, test.y + 3);
                test.size = new Vector2(20, 20);
                floatFieldVal = EditorGUI.FloatField(test,  "fake", floatFieldVal, fakeFieldStyle);

                // Draw FloatField And Texture as a Group
                Rect groupRect = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal(); {     
                    // never create GUIStyle in the loop :)
                    GUIStyle floatIconStyle = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.toolbarButton) {
                        fixedWidth = 20f,
                        margin = new RectOffset(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        padding = new RectOffset(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    };

                    floatFieldVal = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("", floatFieldVal);  
                    // It emulates a texture
                    GUILayout.Label("◀▶", floatIconStyle)

                    // save group rect in a variable
                    if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
                        groupFloatFieldRect = groupRect;

                } EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            } EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();        
        } EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }


    void OnInspectorUpdate() {
        Repaint();
    }    
}
```

Of course all magic numbers are just for a quick example. Also `guiskin` loading and a `GUIStyle` creating shouldn't be in a loop (in this case in `OnGUI`). It's for a quick example too.

`Test.guiskin`is for removing default skin data and regulating other params if needed.

That's how the code above looks:

[screenshot of a window.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byWjR.jpg)

[animated demonstation of fake field.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6VuA.gif)

Answer (score 2):

Just put a label field after the floatfield

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
someFloatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(someFloatValue);
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Change Val")
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

If you want to put a texture, then just create `GUIStyle` with the texture you want as background, and use the style for the label

```
GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();
myStyle.normal.background = myTexture;

EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
someFloatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(someFloatValue);
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("", myStyle)
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Now, to handle widths, just use `GUILayout.Width()`

```
GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();
myStyle.normal.background = myTexture;

EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
someFloatValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(someFloatValue, GUILayout.Width(150));
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("", myStyle)
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Comment: It is not quite what I want. Because mouse behavior over a texture must be the same as over a FloatField label, i.e. if I click on the texture and start dragging a cursor - the float value in the field must changes.

Comment: Sorry for missed information. I thought I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible, but you shouldn't be GUILayout / EditorGUILayout classes. The Layout in the class names means that those variants handle positioning themselves, they each take up a default amount of space and move to the next row, its very conveinient but to do a little bit more advanced stuff, you should use versions of the GUI that take Rect as a position for a draw, so take from GUI/ EditorGUI classes (without Layout in the class name)

I recommend you start by doing a custom PropertyDrawer first, the API for a PropertyDrawer calls for manual element placement, so theres a ton of good examples. Once you start drawing using Rects instead of auto-Layouts there's no limit to how many layers of stuff to paint where, its actually trivial to start painting outside your own inspector (as long as its in the same window)

Comment: I didn't want to make my own GUI system, because Unity already has it)) In fact, I have to write the same logic that already fields has: observing mouse clicking and holding a button, OnFocus/OnBlur events, increasing value in a field etc. It's so sad...So, the only way to do that thing is creating tons of auxiliary classes? :'(

Comment: You would still be using unity's GUI, but they come in two flavours Layout and non Layuout (rect base), they operate in excactly the same way, in fact I suspect the layout versions just wrap around the non-layout ones.

Comment: They use `GetControlRect` and `LastRect` for `EditorGUILayout`: https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEditor/UnityEditor/EditorGUILayout.cs ... I temporarily made a workaround (see my answer). If remove all redundant code that I used for content filling - it will be pretty short... But I will think about using of Property Drawer anyway.